# Where are bookmarks stored for Opera Mini?

Tags: browser

Please tell me in Opera Mini for windows phone, where bookmarks are stored?

Can we copy and paste in other opera mini for windows browser if we have two same window phone  as synchronization is not there so can we use this? any method to use bookmark for other browser?

Answer (score 1):

To see your bookmarks in Opera mini on Windows phone follow these steps

1. Open opera mini
2. Click on the hamburger icon located at the bottom.

[image: Menu bar at the bottom of Opera mini]

3. You should see the bookmarks icon on the left side.

[image: Menu in opera mini]

4. Click on the icon and you can see the bookmarks.